# Center of Gravity derivation question

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames

I need a sanity check, please.

When determining the center-of-gravity of a lamina described by $f(x)$, we know that by definition,

$\bar{x} M = \sum_{i=1}^{N} m_i \tilde{x_i}$

where $\tilde{x_i}$ is the location of the centroid of strip located at $x_i$

Assuming uniform density and thickness, this becomes

$\bar{x} A = \sum_{i=1}^{N} A_i \tilde{x_i}$

or

$\bar{x} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N} A_i \tilde{x_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} A_i}$

Let us consider a stip with width $\Delta x$ at a distance $x_i$ from y-axis

The area of the strip is $\Delta x \times f(x_i)$
The centroid of the strip, $\tilde{x_i}$ will be at a distance $x_i + \Delta x/2$ from y axis

Hence

$\bar{x} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N} (x_i + \Delta x/2)(\Delta x  f(x_i)) }{\sum_{i=1}^{N}\Delta x  f(x_i)} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N} (x_i \Delta x f(x_i)) + ( \frac{\Delta x^2}{2}   f(x_i)) }{\sum_{i=1}^{N}\Delta x  f(x_i)}$

Now, to arrive at the famous equation.

$\bar{x} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N} x_i f(x_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} f(x_i)}$

the term

$\frac{\Delta x^2}{2}   f(x_i)$ is eliminated by some means.

Is this reasoning correct?
Is it because it is safe to assume $\Delta x^2$ is negligible?

Thanks so much

[image]

Comment: Think I figured it out. The strips do not start at $x_i$ but have their centers on that point.

Comment: What's wrong with treating this as an integral over a step function?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to re-invent the integral? When you go from discrete to continuous, you make the intervals infinitely small and you have to sum over a infinite number of "slices", broadly speaking retaining only the terms $\mathscr{O}(\Delta x)$.

**x-coordinate of $G$.**
In the continuous limit, the distance of the center of mass from the $y$-axis becomes

$M x_G = \displaystyle \int_A \rho x dA = \int_{x=0}^{x_1} \int_{y=0}^{p(x)} x \rho dx dy = \int_{x_0}^{x_1} \underbrace{x}_{\text{distance of the cog}\\ \text{from x-axis}} \underbrace{ p(x) dx}_{dm(x)} $.

With the function of the parabola $p(x) = - 4 A \left( \left(\frac{x}{x_1}\right)^2 - \frac{x}{x_1} \right)$, the integral becomes

$M x_G = -4 \rho A x_1^2 \left( \dfrac{1}{4} - \dfrac{1}{3} \right) = \dfrac{1}{3} \rho A x_1^2$. Since the mass reads:

$M = \displaystyle \int_A \rho dA = \int_{x=0}^{x_1} \int_{y=0}^{p(x)} {\rho \,dx dy} = \int_{x=0}^{x_1} \underbrace{\rho p(x) \,dx}_{=dm(x)} = \frac{2}{3} \rho A x_1$,

so that the position of the center of mass is $x_G = \dfrac{1}{2}x_1$.

**y-coordinate of $G$.**
In the continuous limit, the distance of the center of mass of the parabolic lamina from the $x$-axis is given by

$M y_G = \displaystyle \int_A \rho y dA = \int_{x=0}^{x_1} \int_{y=0}^{p(x)} \rho y \,dx dy = \int_{x=0}^{x_1} \rho \dfrac{p^2(x)}{2} dx = \int_{x=0}^{x_1}  \underbrace{\dfrac{p(x)}{2}}_{=y_G(x) \\ \text{ COG of the strip}} \underbrace{\rho p(x) dx}_{= dm(x) \text{ mass os the strip}} $.

where the mass is given by $M = \displaystyle \int_A \rho dA = \int_{x=0}^{x_1} \int_{y=0}^{p(x)} {\rho \,dx dy} = \int_{x=0}^{x_1} \underbrace{\rho p(x) \,dx}_{=dm(x)}$.

Now, with the equation of the parabola $p(x) = -4\frac{A}{x_1^2}x(x-x_1) = -4 A \left( \left(\frac{x}{x_1}\right)^2 - \frac{x}{x_1} \right)$, being $A$ the maximum value, and assuming uniform density $\rho$:

- the mass reads $M = \frac{2}{3} \rho A x_1$,
- the distance of the center of mass from the $x$-axis reads $y_G M = \dfrac{8}{30} \rho A^2 x_1 $ and thus $y_G = \dfrac{2}{5} A$

Answer (score 0):

to obtain the center of mass use those equations

$$y_{CM}=\frac{\iint\,y\,dx\,dy}{A}\\
y_{CM}=\frac{1}{A}\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\left(\int_0^{f(x)}y\,dy\right)\,dx$$

$$x_{CM}=\frac{\iint\,y\,dx\,dy}{A}\\
x_{CM}=\frac{1}{A}\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\left(\int_0^{f(x)}dy\right)\,x\,dx$$

where $~A~$ is the area under the curve $~f(x)~$

$$A=\iint\,dx\,dy=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\,f(x)\,dx$$

$\Rightarrow$

$$y_{CM}=\frac 12\frac{\int_{x_1}^{x_2}f(x)^2\,dx}{\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\,f(x)\,dx}$$

$$x_{CM}=\frac{\int_{x_1}^{x_2}f(x)\,x\,dx}{\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\,f(x)\,dx}$$

with this  function

$$f(x)=a\,(x-x^2)$$

and for example with $~a=2~,x_2=0.4~,x_1=0.2~$ you obtain the results
$~x_{CM}=0.306~,y_{CM}=0.209$

[image]

---

**Remark**

of course you can obtain analytical solution but I didn't put it , because it is too long

the Parable equation is:

$$f(x)=a\,x^2+b\,x+c$$
for your parable you obtain 3 equations for the 3 unknowns $~a,b,c$

$$f(0)=0\\
f(x_f)=0\\
\frac{df}{dx}\Bigg|_{x=\frac{x_f}{2}}=0$$
$\Rightarrow$

$$a\mapsto \pm a\quad, b=-a\,x_f\quad ,c=0$$

with $~x_f=1,f(x)=a\,(x-x^2)$

Comment: With uniform mass distribution, $x_G$ must be on the axis of symmetry of the parabola

Comment: so what is wrong with those equations ? if $~f(x)=b~$ the center of mass is on the symmetry axis . I still think that the equations are correct

Comment: Equations are, results are not. The center of mass of the parabolic area of your example is at $(x_G, y_G) = \left( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{5} \right)$, since the center is on the axis of symmetry, at a height of $\frac{2}{5} y_v$, being $y_v$ the y-coord of the vertex

Comment: I obtain your results if I take $x_1=0~,x_2=1$ but this is special case ?  In my example $x_1=0.2~,x_2=0.4$

Comment: Oh, I missed that you were evaluating the center of gravity for the strip between $x_1 = 0.2$ and $x_2= 0.4$ only

Comment: @basics your equations are exactly my equations! (just multiply by the mass or area)

Comment: Yeah, as I told you the equations are right indeed. I couldn't understand where your numerical results came from (see my last comment)